# How to do a POST json request with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

How can I recreate a request with jquery which would work exactly as this PHP request?

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri);
$response = $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST)
                   ->setRawData(trim($json), 'application/json')
                   ->request();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
$.postJSON("/application/json".
{
  ID:5 // all parameters here for the method 
},
function(data)
{
//data is what comes back from your function
});
```

Comment: postJSON is not an offical jquery function ... but it does indeed work

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
  cache:false,
  type: 'POST',
  url: "yoururl",
  data:yourJsonData,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success:  function(data) {            
  //do what you what with return data
    }
  });
```